# FQL: Users who liked this also liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is is possible to query facebook for information on which pages (on current domain) users liking the current page, also liked? Basically, being able to create a "Users liking this page also liked:", followed by list of pages on the current domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I think you can realistically do this is by subscribing to the edge.create event on a like button and storing it in your own database with the user_id, page address etc.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
```

With FQL,the problem is that you would need to read the 'url_like' table to find this information out, but the only indexable field on this is user_id, which means you could only query for the current active user. If you do want to show the current user other pages on your site they like, you can use a query such as following:

```
 SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me() and strpos(url, 'http://www.example.com') = 0
```

But as I say, for the use case you describe you would need to store this information yourself and then perform your own query to workout the most popular posts. Alternatively the recommendations plugin might meet your needs

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/
```

Comment: I was hoping that something in the lines of the following would be possible
    SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM     url_like WHERE strpos(url, 'http://mydomain.com') = 0)

I know that the user_id is sensitive data, but since it's not part of my end result i thought it would be fine..

Comment: The trouble is you need to provide an indexable field when you query FQL tables. Your inner query "SELECT user_id FROM url_like WHERE strpos(url, 'mydomain.com';) = 0" still doesn't satisfy that condition, so facebook will send you an error response.

Comment: Not the solution I was looking for, but I'm gonna accept your answer for giving an alternative. Thanks.